# Minimum characters to uniquely identify bitcoin trasanction in blockchain

Tags: transactions, sha256, transaction-id, identity

What is the **minimum number of characters** (TXID from the beginning) which is generally considered to uniquely identify a bitcoin transaction in the blockchain?

(Similarly to git and a commit SHA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134627/how-much-of-a-git-sha-is-generally-considered-necessary-to-uniquely-identify-a).